# Can't shake a <td> element just on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, firefox

i'm using jQuery UI to shake some  elements with images inside.

It works well with Chrome, and IE, but not on Firefox.

If I try to shake the img, it starts on a wrong position, but it works. But I can't find the right css for the img to start its animation at its original position.

Here's the code:

```js
function moveAnimations() {
  optionsPokemonOne = {
    effect: "shake",
    times: 1,
    direction: "left"
  };
  optionsPokemonTwo = {
    effect: "shake",
    times: 1,
    direction: "right"
  };

  img_pkm_attack = '/images/pokemon-attacks/' + pokemon1.toLowerCase() + '-2.gif';
  if (imageExist(img_pkm_attack)) {
    img_attack_tag = "<img src='" + img_pkm_attack + "' />";
    $("#pokemons_turn #pokemon1").empty().append(img_attack_tag);
  }
  $('#pokemon1').effect(optionsPokemonOne);

  img_pkm_attack = '/images/pokemon-attacks/' + pokemon2.toLowerCase() + '-2.gif';

  $('#pokemon1').promise().done(function() {
    if (imageExist(img_pkm_attack)) {
      img_attack_tag = "<img src='" + img_pkm_attack + "' />";
      $("#pokemons_turn #pokemon2").empty().append(img_attack_tag);
    }

    $('#pokemon2').effect(optionsPokemonTwo);

    setTimeout(restoreAnimations, 3000);
  });

}
```

```css
#pokemons_turn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 760px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#pokemons_turn td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px #999;
  width: 33%;
}
#pokemons_turn .text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black, -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 3px 3px 5px black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pokemons_turn">
  <tr>
    <td id="player1" class="text">
      <?php echo $playerOne; ?>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="player2" class="text">
      <?php echo $playerTwo; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pokemon1" class="pokemon"></td>
    <td id="vs" class="text">VS</td>
    <td id="pokemon2" class="pokemon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="health1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="health2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pokemon1_name" class="text"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="pokemon2_name" class="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, I'm playing with Pokemons :)

So, is there any workaround for Firefox?

Comment: Is the snippet should work ?

Comment: No, there's a lot more of jQuery code for it to work, I can't post it all. I just posted the snippet of the code where I have the problem.

Comment: I suggest using DIV's to contain your data in the TD. Table elements are a pain--DIV's seem to work much better.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Although it's still kind of glitchy on Firefox, weird.

Comment: It would be nice to see some working code.  This most likely is related to how TDs are displayed (i think *table-cell* instead of *block*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Michael C. Gates suggestion and put Divs inside the  elements that gave me trouble. It's now working fine.

Still no idea why Firefox was the only one giving me this trouble. Oh well.

Comment: As a long-time Pokémon game developer, I can tell you with absolute certainty that, since Firefox 4, that particular browser has sucked harder than IE... Anyway, good luck!